# PHP - write to server folder denied

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have done `chmod -R 777` on the root folder, but I'm still unable to successfully
upload (thus, write) to the uploaded folder!

Do I also have to change the php.ini file?

```
//$target_path = "http://localhost/photoServerProject/uploaded";
$target_path = "/photoServerProject/uploaded";
$fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$upload_location = $target_path.'/'.$fname;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upload_location);

echo 'Moving file: ' . $fname . '</br></br>to: ' . $upload_location;
//echo "<img src=$upload_location>";

if(is_writeable($upload_location)){
    echo '</br></br>Location <strong>is</strong> writeable ';
} else {
    echo '</br></br>Location <strong>is NOT</strong> writeable ';
}
```

### Output:

Moving file: camera.jpeg

to: /photoServerProject/uploaded/camera.jpeg

Location **is NOT** writeable

Comment: Are you testing on a Windows maschine?

Comment: Shouldn't it be your `$target_path` something like `/var/www/photoServerProject/uploaded` and then add writing permissions to that folder for `www-data`

Comment: Just to note that `-r` in `chmod` actually removes read permission. The recursive option is a capital `-R`.

Comment: @djot This is on Mac OSX

Comment: @Horen On my local drive, the path is ~/webdev/photoServerProject/uploaded

Comment: i see you used -R for recursive dirs...have you checked `photoServerProject` and `upload` directory permissions, just to be sure chmod applied correctly.

Comment: @gwillie yes, the permissions are correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding the difference between server and local disk directory structures. Namely, the root folders are different.

I'm surprised nobody brought up this issue.

Here's the solution:

```
<?php

    $local_target = "~/webdev/photoServerProject/uploaded/";
    $server_target = $_server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photoServerProject/uploaded/";

    $fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    $local_file_location = $local_target.$fname;
    $server_file_location = $server_target.$fname;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $local_file_location);

    echo 'Moving file: ' . $fname . '</br></br>to local path: ' . $local_file_location;
    echo '</br></br> But on the server it resides in : ' . $server_file_location;
    echo '</br></br> See?';
    echo "</br></br> <img src=$server_file_location>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$targetPath= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "photoServerProject/uploaded"
```

or

```
$targetPath= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photoServerProject/uploaded"
```

Comment: Keeps saying that location is not writeable. How can I change these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing the difference between paths on my local drive vs server paths. My root folder (localhosts) for server paths is different than my local directory structure.